# Three js scene not rendering

Tags: javascript, three.js

I have an issue with Three js. I created a scene with a 3d model that can rotate and everything worked. Then I tried to do this scene in OOP with javascript but the scene is not rendering and I have a black screen.

Here is my code :

```js
function deg2radians(degs)
{
 return Math.PI * degs / 180.0;
}


var OBJLoaded = function()
{
 this.createRender();
 this.createScenes();
 this.createCamera();
 this.createLights();

 this.loadModel();

 this.render();
};

OBJLoaded.prototype.createRender = function()
{
 var fill = document.getElementById("3dModel");
 this.renderer = Detector.webgl? new THREE.WebGLRenderer( { antialias: true} ): new THREE.CanvasRenderer( {antialias: true} );
 this.renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
 this.renderer.setPixelRatio( window.devicePixelRatio );
 this.renderer.setClearColor(0xBAC4CC);
 fill.appendChild( this.renderer.domElement );
};

OBJLoaded.prototype.createScenes = function()
{
 this.scene = new THREE.Scene();
};

OBJLoaded.prototype.createCamera = function()
{
 this.camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 45, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 2000 );
 this.camera.position.z = 100;
 this.camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
 this.camera.updateProjectionMatrix();

};

OBJLoaded.prototype.createLights = function()
{
 var hemiLight = new THREE.HemisphereLight( 0xffffff, 0xffffff, 0.6 );
 hemiLight.color.setHSL( 1, 1, 1 );
 hemiLight.position.set( 0, 500, 0 );
 this.scene.add( hemiLight );
};

OBJLoaded.prototype.render = function ()
{
 if (this.needupdate) {
  this.renderer.render(this.scene, this.camera);
  this.needupdate = false;
 }
};

OBJLoaded.prototype.loadModel = function()
{
 THREE.ImageUtils.crossOrigin = "anonymous";
 var self = this;
 var loader = new THREE.OBJMTLLoader();
 loader.load( 'skate_tracker.obj', 'skate_tracker.mtl', function ( obj ) {
   obj.position.set(-2, 0, 0);
   obj.rotation.y = -55;
   obj.castShadow = true;
   obj.receiveShadow = true;
   self.model = obj;
   self.scene.add( self.model );
   });
};

OBJLoaded.prototype.newData = function(data)
{
 if (this.model === undefined)
  return;

 this.model.rotation.x = -deg2radians(data[0] + 270);
 this.model.rotation.y =  deg2radians(data[1]);
 this.model.rotation.z =  deg2radians(data[2] + 180);

 this.needupdate = true;
};

var o = new OBJLoaded();

function update()
{
 o.render();
 requestAnimationFrame(update);
}

requestAnimationFrame(update);
```

```html
<head>
<style>
body {margin:0; padding:0;}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div class="item_slider active" id="3d_div" style="display:block;">
 <div class="fill" id="3dModel"></div>
</div>
</body>

<!-- Jquery -->
<script src="js/jquery.js"></script>

<!-- Three.js -->
<script src="js/three.min.js"></script>

<!-- Controls -->
<script src="js/OrbitControls.js"></script>

<!-- Renderer -->
<script src="js/Projector.js"></script>
<script src="js/CanvasRenderer.js"></script>
<script src="js/Detector.js"></script>

<!-- Object loading -->
<script src="js/MTLLoader.js"></script>
<script src="js/OBJMTLLoader.js"></script>
```

So if you can help me understanding what is going wrong, it would be cool :) . Thanks.

EDIT : 
My code without "OOP" that works without any errors.

```js
var scene, camera, renderer, controls;
var object;
var OBJLoaded;

init();
animate();

function animate()
{
 requestAnimationFrame( animate );
 controls.update();
 render();
}

function init() {

 var fill = document.getElementById("3dModel");

 scene = new THREE.Scene();

 camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 45, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 2000 );
 camera.position.z = 100;

 controls = new THREE.OrbitControls( camera );
 controls.damping = 0.2;
 controls.addEventListener( 'change', render );

 //HEMILIGHT
 hemiLight = new THREE.HemisphereLight( 0xffffff, 0xffffff, 0.6 );
 hemiLight.color.setHSL( 1, 1, 1 );
 hemiLight.position.set( 0, 500, 0 );
 scene.add( hemiLight );

 THREE.ImageUtils.crossOrigin = "anonymous";
 var loader = new THREE.OBJMTLLoader();
 loader.load( 'skate_tracker.obj', 'skate_tracker.mtl', function ( object ) {
  var s = 1;
  object.position.set(-2, 0, 0);
  object.scale.set(s, s, s);
  object.rotation.y = -55;
  object.castShadow = true;
  object.receiveShadow = true;
  scene.add( object );
  OBJLoaded = object;
 });
 renderer = Detector.webgl? new THREE.WebGLRenderer( { antialias: true} ): new THREE.CanvasRenderer( {antialias: true} );
 //renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
 renderer.setPixelRatio( window.devicePixelRatio );
 renderer.setClearColor(0xBAC4CC);
 renderer.setSize( fill.offsetWidth, fill.offsetHeight );

 camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
 camera.updateProjectionMatrix();

 renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );

 fill.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

 window.addEventListener( 'resize', onWindowResize, false );
 animate();
}

function onWindowResize() {

 camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
 camera.updateProjectionMatrix();

 renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );

 render();
}

function render()
{
 renderer.render( scene, camera );
}
```

Comment: How did your code look without "OOP"?

Comment: Are you getting any errors?

Comment: I edited my question to add the previous code :)

Comment: Hm, those do look quite different from each other. The OOP version does have this `newData` method which is never called and that `needupdate` flag, while the plain version does have `OrbitControls` which are regularly updated and also reacts to window `resize` events.

Comment: This is why I changed the code. In the older one I can move (with OrbitControls) my 3d model. Then I wanted to inject some datas (x, y, z) to rotate my 3d model and I couldn't do it with the older code so I tried with a more structured "OOP" code.

And about the resize event I just forgot to implement it in the new one.

Comment: So are you calling `o.newData(…)` anywhere?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that in your code the line

```
this.renderer.render(this.scene, this.camera);
```

is never called because you did not initialise the `this.needupdate` flag to `true`. It just stays `undefined`.

Comment: That's right ! Now I initialize my needupdate bool to true at the begining of the class. I have my background render (no more black screen) but my 3d object is still not rendering ...

Comment: Maybe set `self.needupdate = true;` in the load callback, after you `self.scene.add( self.model );`

Comment: Wow ! amazing, that worked, but I'm not really sure to understand why I need to do it in my loader too. Because I initialize it in the class and nothing changes it before the render function. Is it because I'm in a different scope and the needupdate is undefined in this one ?

Comment: No, it is because the loader is asynchronous. In your initialisation, you are only starting the loading. After that, the scene will be rendered empty, and `needupdate` is set to false. Once the model is loaded later, it needs to signal to your animation loop that it wants to be rendered now.